# Geofences keep being removed... Why?

Tags: uwp, windows-10, geofencing

I'm developping a geofence app on Win10 and I'm a bit lost concerning the use of the geofences I create.

Indeed, they keep being removed from the GeofenceMonitor even if I create them specifying the "singleUse" flag as false.

Dwell time is 1s, startTime is being set 5min after Now ("now" being the time the geofence is created), and the duration is set to 1000 days.

I check my geofences (using GeofenceMonitor.Current.Geofences) everytime I start the app, and I remarked that they disappear even when the didn't changed their status. I check the access to the location service before calling the GeofenceMonitor, but its status is really often as "Not Initialized".

I DO NOT use the Clear() method of the monitor to remove them obviously.
I read everything I found on the subject and didn't find any answer, the code provided being exactly the one I use.

For now, the workaround I found is to re-register each geofence when they seem to be removed, and to re-register them too when they trigger a call to my background agent... But it's pretty nasty and there's chance my app misses a trigger because of the disappearing of the geofences.

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I figured what was my problem... There was none !
I was still debugging the app, so I was non-stop debugging/stopping/debugging/stopping the project on my WM10 phone and that's when I was getting my geofences disappearing.

In fact, when you debug then stop the debug again, your app is being "removed" from the device, and even if the settings remain, the geofences are automatically removed from the system.

Using my app normally, I can see the geofences are working (though, not so great sometimes) and do not disappear by themselves.

So, you have to trust MS on this ;)

Have a great day.